# Fetch source file from GitHub using command line tools?

Tags: wget, curl, github

This question is related to a question offsite at [FATAL: MemorySanitizer can not mmap the shadow memory](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memory-sanitizer/lAUkXHte-v0). The person who responded said:

> Do simple tests (e.g. [this one](http://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/test/msan/stack-origin.cc)) work for you?

The link takes me to a GitHub web page at http://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/test/msan/stack-origin.cc, which include the HTML markup. That means I *can't* perform the following with `wget` or `curl`:

```
wget http://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/test/msan/stack-origin.cc
gcc -g2 -fsanitize=memory stack-origin.cc -o stack-origin.exe
```

I'm also trying to avoid the entire clone since I only need the one source file.

How do I fetch the actual source file from GitHub using wget or curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header of the code on the page, you can see Raw. If you check the URL of it by, for example, clicking it, you will see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/master/test/msan/stack-origin.cc and that's what you have to know to use wget.

Comment: Thanks. So do we always use ***`http://raw.githubusercontent.com/`*** as the prefix? Is that the rule? (I ask because I presumed I needed to append something like ***`?source=raw`*** to the URL).

Comment: I don't know (just guess so). But you can always check by downloading the formatted page and look for a similar line:  <a href="/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/raw/master/test/msan/stack-origin.cc" class="btn btn-sm " id="raw-url">Raw</a>